# Tensoring with fraction fields kills the torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, principal-ideal-domains

Assume $R$ is a PID. And $M$ is finitely generated $R$-module. So we have the classification theorem: $M\cong R^r\oplus T(M)$. Is it true that $M\otimes_{R}\mathrm{Frac}(R)=\mathrm{Frac}(R)^r$? At least for $\mathbb{Z}$ it is true.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \otimes\mathbb{Q} =0$ since $a/b=2(a/2b)$ in $\mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: @DouglasMolin So, I can prove like this: let one torsion submodule be $R/(d)$, $1\otimes a/b=1\otimes d a/db=d\otimes a/db=0$? And is it true that $Tor_R^1(M,R)=T(M)$?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your second question but the proof looks correct.

Comment: See Theorem 4.27(2) of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf (the second "direct" proof).  Note that not every tensor in a tensor product is an elementary tensor, but every tensor is a sum of elementary tensors, so it all elementary tensors are $0$ then all tensors are $0$.

Comment: @KCd Thank you for the link. Is it correct that $Tor_1^R(M,R)=T(M)$?

Comment: @CO2 $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,R)=0$ for any $R$-module $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Fr}{Frac}\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}$ Yes, it is true that for a finitely generated $R$-module, with a decomposition $\;M=L\oplus T$, where $T$ is the  torsion submodule of $M$ and $L$ is free of rank $r$, we have
$$M\otimes _R\Fr(R)\simeq \Fr(R)^r.$$

Indeed, the tensor product commutes with direct sums, so $$M\otimes _R\Fr(R)\simeq \bigl(L\otimes _R\Fr(R)\bigr)\oplus\bigl(T\otimes _R\Fr(R)\bigr)\simeq\Fr(R)^r\oplus\bigl(T\otimes _R\Fr(R)\bigr),$$
and as all elements of $T$ are killed by a nonzero element of $R$, which is invertible in $\Fr(R)$, there results that $\;T\otimes _R\Fr(R)=\{0\}$.

As to your question in the comments, it is in general false that $\;\Tor^R_1(M,R)=T$, because $R$ is a *flat* $R$-module, so $\;\Tor^R_1(M, R)=0$ for any $R$-module $M$.

What is true,if $Rˆ$ is a P.I.D., is that
$$\Tor^R_1(M,M)\simeq \Tor^R_1(T,T)\simeq T.$$